# How can I fix Hydration error on first div of an empty hello world page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

i'm trying to learn nextjs (version 13/14) and tried some tutorials on youtube but I'm facing an issue with my firs page when the root html element is a . These tutorials are using  without any problem.

I realized that if I put the root element as  everything works correctly, but why I can't use a div?

Steps to reproduce:

```
npx create-next-app@latest .
✔ Would you like to use TypeScript? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use ESLint? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory? … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) … No / Yes
✔ Would you like to customize the default import alias (@/*)? … No / Yes
```

Then I removed the content of the page.tsx created by the CLI and added a div:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>Hello world</div>
  )
}
```

After that just run npm run dev and received errors:

[image]
[image]

Update:
Problem solved, like @Arnas commented I was using a extension that generate the problem.

Comment: Works for me. https://github.com/ArnasDickus/empty-nextjs-project. Maybe you made some additional changes. I don't see any hydration errors on my side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ArnasDičkus, I downloaded your repo and received the same error :(, detail that the error popup showed up only after an f5 in the browser, but the error was present in the console since start

Comment: Hm... that's weird. I tried in newest safari and chrome in incognito and didn't receive error. Maybe your browser extensions are at fault. Try testing in incognito mode.

Comment: Wow thanks! Tried in the incognito mode and it's working! I gonna try to find which extension is the villain lol

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve the problem

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(Home), { ssr: false });
const Home = () => {
...
...
}
```

Comment: This would disable server side rendering for no actual reason.

Comment: I would like to maintain the SSR active since I'm not doing anything "dynamic" in the hello world